# Max and min of a wire cut into a square and triangle

Tags: calculus, optimization

A piece of wire $10 m$ long is cut into two pieces. One piece is bent into a square and the other is bent into an equilateral triangle. Find the maximum and minimum possible area that can be enclosed. by the wire.

**EDIT:** If $x$ is the length of wire used for the triangle and $10-x$ for the square, I get this formula for the area:
$$A=\frac{(10−x)^2}{16}+\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{36}$$
**EDIT:**
and the endpoints are at $x=0$ and $x=10$.

What do I do next?

Critical point at $A=\dfrac{40\sqrt{3}}{9+4\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange. You are more likely to get a good answer if you tell us what you have tried so far and just where your difficulty is. This tells us just where to help you, and also tells us that you are not just a lazy questioner. So please give us those details.

Comment: On the bottom I did the area and then I used the derivative to find critical points but I keep getting stuck with the min and max

Comment: That is great! You should add your formula for the derivative and give your critical points. Then we could make sure those are correct and help you on the next step.

Comment: $A=\frac{(10−x)^2}{16}+\frac{x^2√3}{36}=\frac{(10−x)^2}{16}+\frac{x^2√3}{36}$
$A'=
the critical points are $x=0$ and $x=10$ is that correct?

Comment: By "add" I meant edit your original question to include this further information. This way everyone can see it clearly, and you get the full formatting available in questions. I'll add these for you.

Comment: Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

After your last editing, you have the correct formula for the total area and the correct endpoints of your domain. However, your critical point is wrong.

You get the critical points by taking the derivative of your formula for total area, setting the resulting expression to zero, and solving for $x$. (You will get only one critical point for this problem). Check that the critical point is in your domain $0 \le x \le 10$. The maximum and minimum areas will then be at two of those three points (two endpoints, one or no critical points).

**EDIT:**

Simplify your area formula:
$$\begin{align}
A(x) & = \frac{(10−x)^2}{16}+\frac{x^2√3}{36} \\
 & = \frac{9(10−x)^2}{144}+\frac{4x^2√3}{144}\\ 
 & = \frac{9(100-20x+x^2)+4\sqrt 3 x^2}{144} \\
 & = \frac{(9+4\sqrt 3)x^2-180x + 900}{144}  \\
\end{align}$$
Setting the derivative to zero:
$$0=A'(x) = \frac{(9+4\sqrt 3)2x-180}{144}$$
$$x=\frac{180}{2(9+4\sqrt 3)}$$
$$x=\frac{90}{9+4\sqrt 3}$$
You now have three possible values of $x$ for the minimum and the maximum: $0$, $10$, and $\frac{90}{9+4\sqrt 3}$. Since your domain is a closed interval, you know the max and min exist and are in that list.

Calculate $A(x)$ for each of these $x$'s. The smallest is your minimum and the largest is your maximum. You can check your answer by graphing your formula for $A(x)$ on a graphing calculator such as [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) or [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Say the length of the piece bent into a triangle is $x$, then the length bent into a square is $10-x$. Can you set up an expression for the are of the square and the triangle now that you know their circumference? If you have the expressions for the area, how do you go about finding maxima and minima?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let the two pieces have lengths $x$ and $10-x$. Using the first piece to form the triangle, we have a triangle of side length $x/3$. Using the second piece to make the square, we have a square of side lenght $\frac{10-x}{4}$. You should know expressions for these areas. Then: $$f(x) = \text{area of triangle} + \text{area of square.}$$

Comment: $A=\frac{(10-x)^2}{16}+ \frac{x^2 √3}{36}=\frac{(10-x)^2}{16}+ \frac{x^2 √3}{36}$
is this right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So what do I do now

Answer (score -2):

let x be side of square and y be side of triangle.
thus 4x+3y=10, y=(10-4x)/3
total area = are of square + area of triangle(equilateral, thus 3 lots of 60* angles, with all sides y length)
A = xx + 1/2 * yy + sin 60*
  = xx + 1/2 *((10-4x)/3)^2)*sqrt(3)/2
  = xx + 1/2 *( (100+16xx-80x)/9 ) * sqrt(3)/2
  = xx + sqrt(3)/36 *(100+16xx-80x)/9)
   Let u =(100+16xx-80x)/9), du/dx = (32x-80)
A'(x)= 2x + sqrt(3)/36 *du/dx
 d (A(x))/dx =    2x + sqrt(3)/36 ((32x-80))
             = x (2 + 32/36*sqrt(3)) -80/36*sqrt(3)
             Thus A'(x)=0,
x (2 + 32/36 *sqrt(3)) -80/36*sqrt(3) = 0
x (2 + 8/9 *sqrt(3)) =20/9*sqrt(3)
x = {20/9 *sqrt(3)}/{(2 + 8/9*sqrt(3))}
x = {2 (10/9 *sqrt(3)/ 2(1 + 4/9*sqrt(3) }
x = (10/9 *sqrt(3))/ (1 + 4/9*sqrt(3) 
x = 10 sqrt(3) / (9 + 4 sqrt (3) )

sign diagram to left of x= 10 sqrt(3) / (9 + 4 sqrt (3)) A'(x) = - , to right is +

Thus its a minimum, moreoever the quadratic equation has coffecient of xx as  + in A(x).
Thus Minimum area = A(10sqrt(3)/(9+4sqrt(3))
                  = 2.719

For max area,
constraint 1,  y = -4x/3 +10,
 
constraint 2, Y and X cant be zero nor negative (they are sides of triangle and square.

Thus in the graph of A(x) the  A(x) is restricted to x > 0, and is maximised as x--> infinity, but y=-4x/3 +10 --> -infinity as x--> infinity.
 
Thus A(x) is maximum at x just before the graph of  y=-4x/3 +10 cuts x axis.
which is just before x = 2.5 
so x= 2.4999999999999999999999999
   Thus as x -->2.5, A(x) --> 6.24999999999999999 mm

Thus A(x max) is  6.25, 
    A(x min)= 2.719 mm